# How to insert data to database using a java mvc

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller, insert

I am trying to insert data into a database using java servlets and an mvc. I have a class called CheckoutDb that uses connection pool and prepared statements to insert data.

```
public class CheckoutDb {
 public static int insert(Checkout checkout) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    String query
            = "INSERT INTO Checkout (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, "
            + "BookTitle, DueDate) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setString(1, checkout.getFirstName());
        ps.setString(2, checkout.getLastName());
        ps.setString(3, checkout.getEmailAddress());
        ps.setString(4, checkout.getBookTitle());
        ps.setString(5, checkout.getFormattedDate());
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

The problem I  seem to be having is actually inserting the data from the controller class.  I have tried gettting the request params from the form and then storing them to the object and then calling the insert method from the CheckoutDb class, but it will not insert any data to the table.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If more code is needed to display, I will provide if needed. Thanks.

```
private String doCheckout(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {


    String firstName= request.getParameter("first_name");
    String lastName= request.getParameter("last_name");
    String emailAddress= request.getParameter("email_address");
    String bookTitle= request.getParameter("book_title");
    Checkout checkout=new Checkout();
    Date date= checkout.getDueDate();


    //TODO: Implement code to check out the book here.
    checkout=new Checkout(firstName,lastName,emailAddress,bookTitle,date);
    CheckoutDb.insert(checkout);
    return "/thankyou.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
After issuing ps.executeUpdate(), you need to issue connection.commit(). That will make the changes permanent to the database and you will be able to see the changes in the database using another connection. JDBC tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html) can give you details on how to manage transactions using commit/rollback.

Comment: yes removed error connection was not started, I started connection and everything display to thank you page correctly, but still the database is empty.

Comment: Dear benzonico, I apologize for this faux pas. I am new to this. I will be careful in future. Thanks for pointing it out. Regards Sandeep

Comment: Samantha, I have given the solution in the original post above. I think, this will solve your problem. Regards Sandeep